# How to define BN layer in pycaffe?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I used this code:

```
conv_bn = L.BN(conv, bn_param=[dict(type='constant', scale_filler=1), dict(type='constant', shift_filler=0.001)], in_place=True)
```

Unfortunately, it outputs some error. The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'BNParameter' object has no attribute 'add'
```

What is the correct method to define a batch normalizaton layer?

This is the prototxt that I want to define use netspec in pycaffe.

```
layer {

  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "conv1_2"
  name: "conv1_2_bn"
  type: "BN"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  bn_param {
    scale_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
    shift_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.001
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @MordechayS AttributeError: 'BNParameter' object has no attribute 'add'